# Merging two lists without duplicates, and calculate the mean of duplicate indices in separate lists

Tags: python, duplicates

I know that the title isn't very clear, so I'll give an example that will make it far easier to understand:

Let's say I have two pairs of lists; [a_time, a_pos], [b_time, b_pos], that I wish to combine based on the values in the 'time' lists (a_time & b_time). However, I also want to calculate the average values in the 'position' lists (a_pos & b_pos) based on the merge between the time lists.

To give some example numbers:

```
a_time = [0, 2]  # order of indices matters, therefore a_time[0] = 0, corresponds to a_pos[0] = 10, etc.
b_time = [1, 2]
a_pos = [10, 9]
b_pos = [9, 11]
```

Here, I could merge the two time lists (removing the duplicates) a number of ways to make 'new_time', such as:

```
new_time = np.unique(a_time + b_time)  # set() could be also used instead of np.unique()
print(new_time)  # [0, 1, 2] (note it does not matter if a list or an array is returned)
```

I would then like to merge the two position lists, to make 'new_pos'. However, both 'a' and 'b' have two matching times (2), so I would like to average the positions at those times, before creating the new list. Hence this stage would look something like:

```
# new_pos = (Some method of merging & averaging based on new_time)
print(new_pos)  # [10, 9, 10] (where the second 10 comes from (9 + 11) / 2, as two times were merged)
```

Does anybody know how to efficiently perform this merging operation?

(This solution would then extend to another parameter pair; 'a_bound' & 'b_bound', where a similar operation to the 'pos' lists would be performed, but I have chosen not to include it in this question to avoid confusion).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This might be more clear if you define a class or named tuple to store all the data for one object. Then you just have a list of objects, and it's easy. What you have now looks like a two step process of reading the objects, and using zip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by `zip`ing the times and positions so you can combine them into one list without losing the associations between the original lists, e.g.:

```
>>> list(zip(a_time, a_pos)) + list(zip(b_time, b_pos))
[(0, 10), (2, 9), (1, 9), (2, 11)]
```

Now you need to group the identical times together.  You could do this all in a single statement with `itertools.groupby` but I think a slightly more verbose operation with `defaultdict` is a little easier to follow:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> positions = defaultdict(list)
>>> for t, p in list(zip(a_time, a_pos)) + list(zip(b_time, b_pos)):
...     positions[t].append(p)
...
>>> list(positions.items())
[(0, [10]), (2, [9, 11]), (1, [9])]
```

Now we just need the averages:

```
>>> from statistics import mean
>>> sorted([(t, mean(p)) for t, p in positions.items()])
[(0, 10), (1, 9), (2, 10)]
```

Or if you just want the positions without the times:

```
>>> [mean(p) for t, p in sorted(positions.items())]
[10, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you!
As a side note, this question has been flagged for being 'not focused'. Do you have any suggested edits to make it more specific to one problem? It'd be nice to see other solutions people might have.